# How to compare Object with Integer in Jade

Tags: pug

How to compare an ObjectID (mongoDB) with Integer(Jade) in Jade/MongoDB?

Example (1):
   `if sensor.id.toString() === '1'`
or
  `if sensor.id.equals(1)`
or 
   `if sensor.id.toString() === "1"`

Return for fist example:

```
h1= sensor.nome 
5| >
6| if sensor.id.toString() === "1" {
7|      div(escaped="text")
8| table(border="1")
9| tr Unexpected token {
```

I have this error for a long time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is not about the comparison but about the `}` bracket. As far as I know there are no brackets for `if statement` in Jade You can see some examples in the [Jade documentation](http://jade-lang.com/reference/conditionals/). Also, if you want to compare the ObjectID, the property is probably `_id` and *not* `id` which is a hash and not an integer.
Does this work for you?

```
- if sensor._id.toString() === "1"
    div(escaped="text)
```